Shift column in dataframe without deleting one
Here is my dataframe:



A
B
C




First
row to delete
row to shift


Second
row to delete
row to shift



And I want this output :



A
B
C




First
row to shift



Second
row to shift




I tried this code :
df.shift(-1, axis=1)



A
B
C




row to delete
row to shift



row to delete
row to shift




The fact is, is there a way to keep the first column not modified ?

Be explicit, chose the columns to affect and reassign (or update):
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value='')

Or:
cols = ['B', 'C']
df[cols] = df[cols].shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value='')

# or
# df.update(df[cols].shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value=''))

Output:
        A             B C
0   First  row to shift  
1  Second  row to shift  

You can do the same per index/column:
cols = ['B', 'C']
idx = [1]
df.loc[idx, cols] = df.loc[idx, cols].shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value='')

# or
# df.update(df.loc[idx, cols].shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value=''))

Output:
        A             B    C
0   First           row  row
1  Second  row to shift     


Okay thank you, and now let's imagine my df is : data = {
'A': ['First', 'Second'],
'B': ['row', 'row to delete'],
'C': ['row', 'row to shift']
} and I want this data = {
'A': ['First', 'Second'],
'B': ['row', 'row to shift'],
'C': ['row', ' ']
}, so I want to shift just one column of a specific row that contains the string 'row to delete', is this possible too ?

@Julio see update

You can shift only the B and C column
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
data = {
    'A': ['First', 'Second'],
    'B': ['row to delete', 'row to delete'],
    'C': ['row to shift', 'row to shift']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

# Shift only the 'B' and 'C' columns
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value='')


print(df)

Output :
        A             B C
0   First  row to shift  
1  Second  row to shift 

